# Re-opened .csv file changes the value of 0.000E+00 number format

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have an excel file where the data is extracted, Column A in the sheet is a 12 digit number which is saved as text in that columns. See below

[[image: 1]]

Further I have a macro build as this file is to be uploaded on web in .csv format which requires few formating to the file too. where the column is converted to 0.000E+00 format and than saved as .csv

The below macro does the required formatting and converts the numbers to 0.000E+00 perfectly. **But when i re-open the .csv file again the numbers are changed**

```
Sub ECRformat()
Dim LR1 As Long
Dim LC1 As Long
Dim rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Apple\Desktop\Salary software - Parikh constructions\Base files shared\ECR-WebUpload.xlsx"
Windows("ECR-WebUpload.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("ECR").Select
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Delete

Windows("ECR-WebUpload.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("ECR").Select
LR1 = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
LC1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count

Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LR1, 1))
rng.Select
With Selection
    .NumberFormat = "0.000E+00"
    .value = .value
End With

Range("A1").Select

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Apple\Desktop\Salary software - Parikh constructions\Base files shared\ECR-WebUpload.csv", _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

Eg : 100199847300 is converted to 1.002E+11 when saved as .csv
**When i re-open the .csv file the value are changed to 1.00E+11 and shows 100200000000.**

Comment: Open the file in Notepad instead.

Comment: Hi Rory, i have tried that already.. But the file that saved in .csv converts the number. I believe its rounding off the number

Comment: When you save as csv it saves the formatted value. It's really not clear why you are doing what you're doing if that is not what you want to happen.

Comment: @Rory *Almost* correct ;) It saves and ***rounds*** the formatted value. See my rewritten answer for more details.

Comment: @robinCTS When I say 'formatted value' I mean the value you *see*.

Comment: @Rory Ah yes. Very similar to the point of confusion *I* was involved in! I take my previous comment back :) ***Absolutely*** correct!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** Rolled all the previous edits into one, and clarified things. (Thanks [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7512742/adam-vincent) for making me realize I'd been less than clear.)

That's just how Excel behaves when importing a .csv. It converts the "numbers", which are stored as text, to real numbers and then *displays* them in the way it thinks is best. (Which for 12-digit numbers is scientific notation.)

You have to re-format the numbers every time you re-open the file if you want to display them differently.

If you want non-scientific notation use:

```
.NumberFormat = "0"
```

or for scientific notation with full decimal places use:

```
.NumberFormat = "0.00000000000E+00"
```

However, if you wish to *save* the .csv you ***MUST*** set the display number format to `"0"`, **otherwise Excel rounds to four* significant places!** Using the number format `"0.00000000000E+00"` won't cause rounding, but *will* result in the number being *stored* in scientific notation.

For your particular case, since the numbers in the original Excel file are stored as text, all you need to do is open the file and "save as" a .csv file for no rounding to occur. No need to run the macro at all.

After that the .csv will behave just as you expect, i.e., *displaying* as scientific notation in Excel, whilst showing the *real* non-scientific values in Notepad. **Provided you don't save the .csv file in Excel again without changing the number format to `"0"`.**

---

<sub>* Four is for the default scientific notation Excel uses. If a custom scientific notation number format is used the number of significant digits used for rounding corresponds directly to the format. And the number is stored in scientific notation as well.</sub>

Comment: Hi Robin, Thanks for explaining how excel behaves. I've to make the format changes to the excel file. Convert the text to number format and than save as .csv which i would later open in notepad and replace "," to #~#. But currently when i save the .csv it changes the number itself. I believe its rounding the number

Comment: @JigarRathod Yes. That's because Excel converts the number to text. However, it doesn't use the stored number. It uses the ***displayed*** number. I'll update the answer with how to stop the rounding.

Comment: this work like a treat... converting into .csv on reopen doesnot change the number now.. but when open in notepad it shows 1.00199847251E+11 instead of the actual number. In .csv i want it in scientific but in notepad non-scientific

Comment: I have a file which does that and want to implement the same on my macro and file. Is there a way i can upload/attach the file here. So you can look through?

Comment: @JigarRathod That can't be done. If you need need the .csv in  scientific notation for uploading to the web then that's what you have to have to save it for. I'm not sure why you are replacing `,` with `#~#` in notepad, but if you could do this in Excel itself.

Comment: @JigarRathod You have to use an external file sharing site and post the link here.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yjv7g93xqykrxdc/PF%20Uploaded%20File%20-%20Step%203.csv?dl=0 Hi Robin file attached on this link is doing exactly that i want in the .csv its in scientific notations but when accessed using notepad it shows the whole number without scientific notations. This is exactly that i want to achieve by this code & once this issue is resolved.. if we open this .csv file in notepad it has "," to seperate the columns i want to use #~# instead

Comment: @JigarRathod I've updated the answer and made it *much* clearer.

Comment: Works superbly Robin... ur a superman. :) one last question -  will my macro make the changes of "," to "#~#" into notepad ?

Comment: @JigarRathod That *is* possible. What file extension do you want it saved as? Surely you don't want `.csv`?

Comment: .csv part is sorted. Now i want to open the .csv in notepad replace the "," with "#~#" and save as text document - notepad file. That's the final file which will get uploaded on the web

Comment: This is completely sorted. I was able to achieve my requirement. Thanks a lot Robin for all your expert guidance & assistance. Just one more favor, if you can assist me on my one unanswered question on stackoverflow. here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46151437/6-months-rolling-data-set-to-be-created-in-vba

Answer (score 1):

So everyone keeps saying "This is how Excel behaves when encountering a number".. Which misses the mark. To clarify..

Excel by default will DISPLAY your 12 digit number in scientific notation, just as typing a web address will display your string as a hyperlink.

**NumberFormat is a visual representation of the value.**

CSV files store comma separated values, and that's it.  You cannot apply a number format and save that number format in a CSV file.

If you must apply a number format, you have to save it as an Excel file to preserve the formatting.

Otherwise, you must edit the VALUE of the cell to be scientific notation and save that as CSV.

One way to accomplish this is to

1. CUT (CTRL-X) your numbers displayed as scientific notation
2. Format Cells as Text
3. PASTE into Notepad
4. Then paste it back into Excel.
5. Save as CSV

Result: You now have scientific notation when opening your CSV file in notepad.

If you find a better way, please comment below.

Comment: Actually, Jigar *doesn't* want scientific notation in notepad. He wants scientific notation in excel and normal numbers in notepad. All he needs to do is save his original workbook as a .csv and everything works fine. And yes, I should have been clearer when I said  to "convert numbers" that I meant "and have them display as/for display purposes".

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.  I got lost in the back and forth.

Comment: And thanks for prompting me to rewrite my answer. Your answer actually misses an important point and gets one wrong. You *can* apply a number format and save that format to a CSV file. For example, `"0"` saves as a normal integer number, `"0.0"` saves to one decimal place, whilst `"0E+00"` saves as scientific notation. The important point missed is that Excel *rounds* numbers before saving unless `"0"` is used. Also, steps 1-4 of your process are redundant. Step 5 will work by itself. See my answer for further details.

Comment: Learning has occurred =)